# Что нужно знать, прежде чем изучать C++

Tags: c++

Хочу начать изучать, и что бы не было трудностей с понятиями и структурами

Comment: А что вы сейчас знаете? Какие языки?

Comment: Единственное, что нужно знать - зачем вам это и чего вы хотите достигнуть изучением этого языка.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Вообще, классический вариант - выучить `C`, после этого выучить `C++`.*

Правда большая проблема людей, избравших такой путь изучения в том, что они не понимают, что `C++` и `C` - совершенно разные языки и продолжают писать код `C++` примерно так же, как бы они делали на `C`, что в корне неверно.

Для изучения `C` могу порекомендовать [**The C Programming Language,**](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2480925/) для изучения `C++` - [**C++ Primer.**](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2480925/)

Как только освоите их, рекомендую серьезно прочитать и обдумать [**C++ FAQ Lite,**](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/) и [**C++ FQA Lite,**](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/) в свое время они достаточно сильно изменили мой подход к программированию.

Answer (score 1):

Просто начни изучать, по ходу дела со всем разберешься.