# Как создать свой модуль на С++

Tags: c++

Помогите пожалуйста, как создовать собсвенные модули на С++, если не трудно, лучше на примере.

Comment: Объясните поподробнее, что вы подразумеваете под словом **модуль** ?

Файл, который отдельно компилируется (из исходного текста на C++) или динамически загружаемую разделяемую библиотеку или что-то еще ?

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, вместо того, чтобы задавать такие вопросы пачками, лучше всего взять какую-либо хорошую книжку по `C++` и начать по ней заниматься.

**Просто то, что на такие вопросы вам ответят здесь, будет, скорее, лишь некоторым частичным пересказом сути, может быть, даже неправильным.**

---

Про один из возможных подходов к изучению `C++` с соответствующими книгами можете посмотреть [**здесь.**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/49479/%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-c?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1#49587)

Comment: поддерживаю

Answer (score 0):

я всецело поддерживаю мнение Котика,*который*хочет_кушать
но если это всерьёз надо, то модули в C++ называются заголовочные файлы и пишутся очень просто(в отдельный файл добавляется нужный вам код, файл помещается в ту-же папку, что и исходный код программы(притом он должен иметь англ. название и расширение .h, .hpp), а в самой программе пишется #include "header.h" именно в кавычках и именно с расширением).
о том, что писать в самом файле не поленитесь почитать специальную литературу.

Comment: Не путайте человека. Заголовочные файлы и модули - это совсем разные вещи.

Comment: простите, но я так понял вопрос-я подумал, что вопрос о модулях, которые хедеры в С++, но модули в паскале.

Comment: Которые суть модули из модулы-2 (или их производные)